# Screen resolution and battery life

Tags: linux, windows, display

I know that a 4k display will use up more battery life then a 1080p based display, so my question is, if I drop the pixels from 4k to 1080p will battery life be improved even if the screen on a laptop is still technically a 4k display screen?

Is it pixels that determains battery usage because the graphics card as to generate all those pixels?

Comment: Yes, well most likely... The amount of battery it will save could vary widely based on a variety of factors like GPU, screen type/technology, and other factors. Without specific testing, the battery saving could be anywhere from negligible to significant. But the point is it is not just pixels that determines battery usage.

Comment: I would not expect that. Most of the screen's energy is consumed by the background illumination, and the display must perform some upscaling (unless it doesn't, which is probably not what you want). The pixel clock of the GPU can be reduced but the impact will not be very high unless lots of rendering is performed. In other words, that would roughly depend on whether you're running 3D games or a 2D desktop. Just my guess; you'll have to try.

Comment: Related: [This older post](https://superuser.com/q/974045/109256) had asked "Does changing the screen resolution affect power consumption?". However the only answer at the time mentioned power consumption by display monitor, but *not* graphics card.